# How can I design my PCB in a way I can debug the Atmel microcontroller on board?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, atmel, debugging, swd

We are designing a board around Atmel SAM4E microcontroller, and use Atmel-ICE for debugging/programming. To save space, we would like to avoid including the whole ICE connector. Which are the minimum set of required pins so that I can still program and debug over SWD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atmel shares JTAG and SWD pins on their ICs. The SAM4E [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel_11157_32-bit-Cortex-M4-Microcontroller_SAM4E8-SAM4E16_Datasheet.pdf) says it clearly:

[image: SWD & JTAG pins sharing]

SWD is (in most cases) a two-wire interface, so the only program/debug connection is *TMS/SWDIO* and *TCK/SWDCLK*.

Comment: Will a three wire interface (SWDIO/SWCLK/GND) allow programming the internal flash as well?

Comment: @AtillaFiliz We don't count GND as a signal wire. But yeah.